# Why am I getting Error: 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/"project name"/agent' denied

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am getting this error even though I am like 90% sure I setup dialogflow and cloud correctly.
Here is my code

```
dfProjectID = "(project id)" # Went in the cloud console dashboard and copied the project id
dfLanguageCode = "en"
sessionID = "eXwjQ7Zsd8" # Can be any string
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "C:\\Users\\zbeb\\Documents\\GitHub\\Programming\\Python\\Voice Assistant\\qwerty-rapy-cc383727ea4d.json"


def DialogFlow(textToAnalyze):
    sessionClient = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
    session = sessionClient.session_path(dfProjectID, sessionID)
    textInput = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=textToAnalyze, language_code=dfLanguageCode)
    queryInput = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=textInput)

    try:
        response = sessionClient.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=queryInput)
        print(f"Query text: {response.query_result.query_text}")
        echoIntent = response.query_result.intent.display_name
        print(f"Detected intent: {echoIntent} | Detected intent confidence: {response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence}")
        answer = response.query_result.fulfillment_text
        print(f"Answer: {answer}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        answer = "N/U"
        echoIntent = "N/U"
        print("Dialogflow connection error")
        pass

    if answer != "N/U":
        # Speak(answer)
        voice.generate_and_play_audio(answer, playInBackground=False)

    return echoIntent
```

I tried changed the google account, deleting the dialogflow project and starting a new one, creating a new key, adding roles like "Dialogflow API Admin" and "Dialogflow API Client", creating a new service account...